# Javascript "For loops" difference between i-5 and i=-5

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I want a loop that starts with `i=100`, and decrements by 5 on each iteration. However, this produces an error:

```
 for(var i=100;i>=1;i-5)
    {
        document.write(i+"<br />");
    }
```

But 'i=i-5' works:

```
for(var i=100;i>=1;i=i-5)
    {
        document.write(i+"<br />");
    }
```

Why?

The question is how we can assign a variable to a variable i=i-5.I go the question answered I taught "i=i-5" was a expression the value of i variable is i-5 and no calculation happen its just a stable variable.
The answer is that it is taking a the i value and subtracting it by 5 and not assigning.

Comment: You probably meant to type in `i = i - 5`.

Comment: You might be looking for `i -= 5` which will decrease the value of `i` by 5 each iteration of the loop, but the question is hard to understand. `i - 5` does not assign anything, so the value of `i` does not change. This will cause an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just write i - 5, there is no left-hand variable, which means there is nothing which is taking the value of i and subtracting it by 5. If you write i = i - 5 then you will decrement 5 since you now have a left-hand variable.

Comment: If I assign i=i-5 then we are changing the value of i to i-5.We want i=100-5.How can we assign a variable to its same variable ? i=i

Comment: Also, it’s kind of important to point out that the third part in the head of a `for` loop gets executed after every execution of the loop’s body. @JessePinkman Please read [how `for` loops work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Comment: i is initially 100, so that is the value of i on the right hand, so you get i = 100 - 5, which makes i = 95. Next loop you will have i = 95 - 5 to get 90, and so on.